# Best way to do set arithmetic in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, set-operations

Member-Role is N:N relationship.

```
Member           MemberRole       Role
+----------+     +----------+     +----------+
| Id       |     | MemberId |     | Id       |
| ...      |     | RoleId   |     | Name     |
+----------+     +----------+     +----------+
```

- There are ~15,000 members, which have a varying and possibly zero number of roles.
- There are ~50 roles.

Outside of the database, I have allow-deny lists I need to check against the database. A list might look like

```
+a -b +c +d
```

This means:

1. If has role *a*,

   1. ALLOW
2. Else,

   1. If has role *b*,

      1. DENY
   2. Else,

      1. If has role *c*,

         1. ALLOW
      2. Else,

         1. If has role *d*,

            1. ALLOW
         2. Else,

            1. DENY

For example, someone with roles *a* and *d* would allowed, while someone with roles *b* and *d* would be disallowed.

The lists can easily be converted into a mathematical equation by starting from the end, applying a union (∪) for `+` terms and a difference (-) for `-` terms.

`+a -b +c +d` ⇒ ( ( ( ∅ ∪ d ) ∪ c ) - b ) ∪ a

Any trailing deny (`-`) can be ignored, so we know the first will always be a union.

`+a -b +c +d` ⇒ ( ( d ∪ c ) - b ) ∪ a

From that, I can build the following query:

```sql
       SELECT `MemberId` FROM `MemberRole` WHERE `RoleId` = @d
UNION  SELECT `MemberId` FROM `MemberRole` WHERE `RoleId` = @c
EXCEPT SELECT `MemberId` FROM `MemberRole` WHERE `RoleId` = @b
UNION  SELECT `MemberId` FROM `MemberRole` WHERE `RoleId` = @a
```

Since x - y = x ∩ y', we can also derive

`+a -b +c +d` ⇒ ( ( d ∪ c ) ∩ b' ) ∪ a

From that, I can build the following query:

```sql
SELECT `Id`
  FROM `Member`
 WHERE (
           (
               EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `MemberRole` WHERE `MemberId` = `Member`.`Id` AND `RoleId` = @d )
               OR
               EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `MemberRole` WHERE `MemberId` = `Member`.`Id` AND `RoleId` = @c )
           )
           AND
           NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `MemberRole` WHERE `MemberId` = `Member`.`Id` AND `RoleId` = @b )
       )
       OR
       EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `MemberRole` WHERE `MemberId` = `Member`.`Id` AND `RoleId` = @a )
```

What's the best way to check if a member is allowed? (The answer will usually be yes.) Would using `WITH` help?

Note that the items of the allow-deny list can be role ids (number) or role names (not a number).

Comment: `EXISTS() AND/OR NOT EXISTS()`

Comment: @wildplasser Like in the query I've just added to the question?

Comment: Yes, but you could regroup them, using `roleid IN(d,c) ...`

Comment: @wildplasser These queries will be build dynamically since the lists will come from config files. That's a tad trickier, but doable.

Comment: I didn't say I couldn't. I just said it would be a bit trickier. It would require adding look ahead, which isn't that hard, but it is an extra element. /// It wouldn't help much in the example (combining only two of the EXISTS). but it would actually help more in practice.

Answer (score 2):

This *allow* rule `+a -b +c +d` can be described by logical expression `a + !b(c + d)`.

```
WITH MemberRole_acl AS (
  SELECT memberId,
    SUM(roleId = 'a') AS rolesA,
    SUM(roleId = 'b') AS rolesB,
    SUM(roleId = 'c') AS rolesC,
    SUM(roleId = 'd') AS rolesD
  FROM MemberRole
  GROUP BY memberId
)
SELECT m.*
FROM Member m
JOIN MemberRole_acl r ON r.memberId = m.id
WHERE rolesA OR NOT rolesB AND (rolesC OR rolesD)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c3d8c77921cadadd58811be91b89563d)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the names of the roles as @a, @b, @c and @d, you can join the tables, aggregate and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT mr.memberid
FROM MemberRole mr INNER JOIN Role r
ON r.Id = mr.RoleId
WHERE r.Name IN (@a, @b, @c, @d)
GROUP BY mr.memberid
HAVING MAX(r.Name = @a) OR NOT MAX(r.Name = @b);
```

If you have the ids of the roles as @a, @b, @c and @d, it is simpler:

```
SELECT memberid
FROM MemberRole 
WHERE RoleId IN (@a, @b, @c, @d)
GROUP BY memberid
HAVING MAX(RoleId = @a) OR NOT MAX(RoleId = @b);
```